# Zuckerman's "Sets and Transfinite Numbers"

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, book-recommendation

I am beginning a study in set theory and I found an old book in my school's library by Martin Zuckeman called *Sets and Transfinite Numbers* which was published in the 1970's. Has anyone used this text and should I look for a text that is more "current"? I've had basic set theory and this will be my first go at more serious material.

Comment: Perhaps Halbeisen's book is a good start; Jech is reasonable too. Levy's "Basic Set Theory" is also a viable option.

Comment: Zuckerman's book offers some solutions to the exercises which I think may be helpful since I'm studying independently. Is this an important feature of an intro text?

Comment: To some degree, it's important. Halbesien's book doesn't really have exercises though, so you might want to reconsider that. As for other books, you can always try for yourself and see if it worked out fine or not. If you're not sure, you can look online and/or ask here for hints or critique of your solutions. (Be sure to search first, many of the standard exercises have been asked and answered here before.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Halbesien's book doesn't really have exercises" But it is full of interesting open problems. :-)

Comment: @Andres: Yeah, whenever I see someone has solved a three-stars problem in Jech's choice book (e.g. model without uncountable regular cardinals; the consistency of $\sf AD$; etc.) I like to say that they just solved a difficult exercise in Jech's book. :-)